# Can mongoDB aggegation pipeline create objects from keys and values?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a mongoDB aggregation pipeline, which currently results in data in this form:

```
{ year:2014, item:'a', value:1}
{ year:2014, item:'b', value:2}
{ year:2014, item:'c', value:3}
{ year:2015, item:'a', value:2}
{ year:2015, item:'b', value:3}
{ year:2015, item:'c', value:4}
```

What is the best way to transform this to:

```
{year:2014, a:1, b:2, c:3}
{year:2015, a:2, b:3, c:4}
```

I imagine this could be done with map-reduce, but I wondered if anyone had an elegant way to do it using the aggregation pipeline.

By the way, there could be hundreds of different possible item values -- more than just the three (a,b,c) I used in the example above. There are too many to use Yathish's approach below.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try the below piece of code :

```
db.[collection].aggregate([
{
 $project : { year : 1,     
             "newKey" : { "$cond" : 
                              { if :   { "$eq" :["$item","a"] }, 
                                then : { "a" : "$value" }, 
                                else : { "$cond" : 
                                              { if : { "$eq": ["$item","b"] }, 
                                                then : {"b":"$value"}, 
                                                else : { $cond :
                                                             { if:{"$eq":["$item","c"] },
                                                               then: { "c":"$value" },
                                                               else : false 
                                                             }
                                                       }
                                               }
                                       } 
                               } 
                        }

            }
},
{
 $group : { 
            _id:"$year", 
            newKey : { $push : "$newKey" }
          }
}
]);
```

Comment: Hey thanks, Yathish. Good idea. I hadn't thought of doing it like that. It would be a solution if I could know all possible item names in advance. I'll add that constraint to my question.